# abraham/twitteroauth cannot see [unwound] object in entities->urls

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

i am using abraham/twitteroauth for twitter feed. Everything works normal as expected, just cannot get [unwound] object as explained on twitter for developers website.

```
object(stdClass)#7 (25) {

  ["entities"]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#16 (4) {

    ["urls"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
      [0]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#17 (4) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(23) "link"
        ["expanded_url"]=&gt;
        string(73) "https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/7-ted-talks-every-designer-should-watch/"
        ["display_url"]=&gt;
        string(33) "invisionapp.com/blog/7-ted-tal…"
        ["indices"]=&gt;
        array(2) {
          [0]=&gt;
          int(46)
          [1]=&gt;
          int(69)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In Twitter for developers website i see unwound.  But in my var_dump i cant find.

```
{"urls": [
      {
        "url": "link",
        "expanded_url": "link",
        "display_url": "link",
        "unwound": {
          "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0",
          "status": 200,
          "title": "RickRoll'D",
          "description": "http://www.facebook.com/rickroll548 As long as trolls are still trolling, the Rick will never stop rolling."
        },
        "indices": [
          62,
          85
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Maybe have some ideas ? Appreciate for help!:)

Comment: Should you then not report this to Abraham and not us?

Comment: Try a `print_r($yourobject);` It looks to me like whatever you are using to dump that object is truncating the bit you are interested in

Comment: @RiggsFolly yep i already created issue on this, but though maybe there is something wrong with my code and someone had same problem as me:)